# Custom New Item Form did not updated automatically after updating Survey Questions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, survey-list

I have created Custom New Item Form in my Survey list using SPD. When I edited one of my Question that updated question was not reflected to my Custom form.
When I check default `NewForm.aspx`, question was updated there.

Is there any other way that questions on the custom form updates automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you create a Custom form, you are breaking the automatic associations where an updated question (or field in the case of standard lists) automatically shows up. You must maintain your custom form any time you make structural changes to your list or it isn't reflected.